# How to make a face out of a sphere section in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Trying to close this sphere section that is created by delete geometry node and position selection. How do I add make a face connecting the top open edges?

[image]

Note that in the screenshot, only the frame titled mantle is connected to output for simplification

Answer (score 2):

Solved using Attribute Statistic and Transfer Attribute

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all you need to do here is select the points along the open edge, and convert them into a mesh.

You can solve this as follows:

[image]

1. Convert only the points along the open edge into a curve with `Mesh to Curve`.
2. Convert this curve into a mesh with `Fill Curve`.
3. By converting the curve, its position was set to 0, so move it back to the position of the original curve.

*PS: If you are using Blender 3.3, then you should apply the node `Transfer Attribute` instead of `Sample Index`.*

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4)*</sub>